# Operator realizations of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I want to realize the algebra $A_q(\tilde{S}^{n-1})$ as introduced in the acticle of Dijkhuizen and Noumi (http://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9605017v1.pdf) as bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$. Can someone give an idea how to start with such a realization (choice of $H$ and choice of operators)?

Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe it is esasier to start with a representation for $U_q(sl(n))$?